# Technology used in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

Today i am trying to explain to my friend that how many technologies are used in magento and i am searching for list of technologies used in magento but couldn't find it so i prepare a list of things by myself that requires to learn and understand magento (language, pattern, framework) but i am missing something here

Here is the list

Php

Css

JavaScript

Sql

jQuery

Bootstrap

Zend

Symphony

Xml

Oops

Mvc

EAV

Mvvc

Prototype

Required Js

Knockout js

Ui components

Composer

CSS preprocessing

Less

This list is not complete can you help me to complete this list

It would be great if list of technologies are separate for Magento and magento 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Third-party libraries (Zend Framework 1, Zend Framework 2, Symfony)
- Coding standards PSR-0 (autoloading standard), PSR-1 (basic coding
  standards), and PSR-2 (coding style guide), PSR-3, PSR-4
- Redis
- Memcache
- Varnish
- Solr (Magento Enterprise Edition only
- Elasticsearch (Magento Enterprise Edition version 2.1.x only)
- Nginx
- HTML5
- CSS3
- REST
- SOAP

Source : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/tech-stack.html

---

responsive.js

menu.js

matchMedia.js, used by responsive.js and menu.js

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_js.html

Comment: i will check and provide some more list

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a fairly complete list here, or at least it adds a few more http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/tech-stack.html

Comment: Thanks  but it is not covered all technologies frameworks and architectural pattern like mvc,oops,mvvc i need hole list